# Storing long text in Google Datastore as string (PHP)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to store a JSON object in Google Datastore which is greater than 500 characters. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Properties_and_value_types) :

> **stringValue: string**
>
> *Up to 500 Unicode characters if property is indexed, up to 1MB otherwise*

So when I try to add slighlly longer than 500 characters **unindexed** string I get the following exception:

> The string property details has a value that is too long. It cannot
>   exceed 500 characters

When I try to do the same from Google's console, I get an error (see screenshot), if I shorten the string to make it less than 500 characters, it works fine[image]

Does anybody know what the proper/recommended way for adding longer than 500 chars strings is?

Comment: It looks like this is a bug with the cloud console where it is using the wrong type (StringProperty versus Text). However, the code you write should be able to store unindexed properties. Can you provide a code snippet here?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it is a bug in App Engine Cloud Console.
I have the same issue with the console, and I store a lot of strings that are 500+ characters from code.

I would take the following approach:

- Add the string by code.
- Send feedback on the problem to the App Engine Team.